# Running in "undefined method `to_sym' for nil:NilClass" when using activeadmin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activeadmin

I've installed activeadmin to my ruby-on-rails project. I can see every model except for one. When I click on the link for this model in the headbar I get an errorpage that says:

```
undefined method `to_sym' for nil:NilClass
Extracted source (around line #2):
insert_tag renderer_for(:index)
```

The model that doesn't work is the only model with has-many-through relations. Here is the code of the model:

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :person
belongs_to :regularity

has_many :groupings
has_many :groups, through: :groupings

has_many :localizations
has_many :locations, through: :localizations

has_many :categorizations
has_many :kategorien, through: :categorizations

has_many :agings
has_many :ages, through: :agings

accepts_nested_attributes_for :groupings
accepts_nested_attributes_for :localizations
accepts_nested_attributes_for :categorizations
accepts_nested_attributes_for :agings
accepts_nested_attributes_for :groups
accepts_nested_attributes_for :locations
accepts_nested_attributes_for :kategorien
accepts_nested_attributes_for :ages

def LinkToKategorie (arr)
    arr.each do |kat|
        Categorization.create(kategorie: kat, project: self)
    end
end

def LinkToLocation (arr)
    arr.each do |loc|
        Localization.create(location: loc, project: self)
    end
end

def LinkToGroup (arr)
    arr.each do |gro|
        Grouping.create(group: gro, project: self)
    end
end

def LinkToAge (arr)
    arr.each do |ag|
        Aging.create(age: ag, project: self)
    end
end
end
```

Here is the full trace of the error:

```
activerecord (4.1.8) lib/active_record/reflection.rb:100:in `_reflect_on_association'
activerecord (4.1.8) lib/active_record/reflection.rb:537:in `source_reflection'
activerecord (4.1.8) lib/active_record/reflection.rb:575:in `chain'
/home/oscar/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/bundler/gems/activeadmin-988b34e77d1f/lib/active_admin/filters/resource_extension.rb:131:in `block in default_association_filters'
/home/oscar/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/bundler/gems/activeadmin-988b34e77d1f/lib/active_admin/filters/resource_extension.rb:131:in `reject!'
/home/oscar/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/bundler/gems/activeadmin-988b34e77d1f/lib/active_admin/filters/resource_extension.rb:131:in `default_association_filters'
/home/oscar/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/bundler/gems/activeadmin-988b34e77d1f/lib/active_admin/filters/resource_extension.rb:111:in `default_filters'
/home/oscar/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/bundler/gems/activeadmin-988b34e77d1f/lib/active_admin/filters/resource_extension.rb:96:in `filter_lookup'
/home/oscar/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/bundler/gems/activeadmin-988b34e77d1f/lib/active_admin/filters/resource_extension.rb:25:in `filters'
/home/oscar/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/bundler/gems/activeadmin-988b34e77d1f/lib/active_admin/filters/resource_extension.rb:154:in `block in filters_sidebar_section'
/home/oscar/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/bundler/gems/activeadmin-988b34e77d1f/lib/active_admin/helpers/optional_display.rb:25:in `instance_exec'
/home/oscar/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/bundler/gems/activeadmin-988b34e77d1f/lib/active_admin/helpers/optional_display.rb:25:in `display_on?'
/home/oscar/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/bundler/gems/activeadmin-988b34e77d1f/lib/active_admin/resource/sidebars.rb:17:in `block in sidebar_sections_for'
/home/oscar/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/bundler/gems/activeadmin-988b34e77d1f/lib/active_admin/resource/sidebars.rb:17:in `select'
/home/oscar/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/bundler/gems/activeadmin-988b34e77d1f/lib/active_admin/resource/sidebars.rb:17:in `sidebar_sections_for'
/home/oscar/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/bundler/gems/activeadmin-988b34e77d1f/lib/active_admin/views/pages/base.rb:112:in `sidebar_sections_for_action'
/home/oscar/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/bundler/gems/activeadmin-988b34e77d1f/lib/active_admin/views/pages/base.rb:136:in `skip_sidebar?'
/home/oscar/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/bundler/gems/activeadmin-988b34e77d1f/lib/active_admin/views/pages/base.rb:74:in `build_page_content'
/home/oscar/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/bundler/gems/activeadmin-988b34e77d1f/lib/active_admin/views/pages/base.rb:52:in `block (2 levels) in build_page'
arbre (1.0.3) lib/arbre/element/builder_methods.rb:31:in `block in build_tag'
arbre (1.0.3) lib/arbre/context.rb:92:in `with_current_arbre_element'
arbre (1.0.3) lib/arbre/element/builder_methods.rb:49:in `with_current_arbre_element'
arbre (1.0.3) lib/arbre/element/builder_methods.rb:26:in `build_tag'
arbre (1.0.3) lib/arbre/element/builder_methods.rb:39:in `insert_tag'
arbre (1.0.3) lib/arbre/element/builder_methods.rb:14:in `div'
/home/oscar/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/bundler/gems/activeadmin-988b34e77d1f/lib/active_admin/views/pages/base.rb:48:in `block in build_page'
arbre (1.0.3) lib/arbre/context.rb:92:in `with_current_arbre_element'
arbre (1.0.3) lib/arbre/element/builder_methods.rb:49:in `with_current_arbre_element'
/home/oscar/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/bundler/gems/activeadmin-988b34e77d1f/lib/active_admin/views/pages/base.rb:47:in `build_page'
/home/oscar/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/bundler/gems/activeadmin-988b34e77d1f/lib/active_admin/views/pages/base.rb:10:in `build'
arbre (1.0.3) lib/arbre/element/builder_methods.rb:30:in `block in build_tag'
arbre (1.0.3) lib/arbre/context.rb:92:in `with_current_arbre_element'
arbre (1.0.3) lib/arbre/element/builder_methods.rb:26:in `build_tag'
arbre (1.0.3) lib/arbre/element/builder_methods.rb:39:in `insert_tag'
/home/oscar/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/bundler/gems/activeadmin-988b34e77d1f/app/views/active_admin/resource/index.html.arb:2:in `block in __home_oscar__rbenv_versions_______lib_ruby_gems_______bundler_gems_activeadmin____b__e__d_f_app_views_active_admin_resource_index_html_arb___4298410947655854879_70101451315680'
arbre (1.0.3) lib/arbre/context.rb:45:in `instance_eval'
arbre (1.0.3) lib/arbre/context.rb:45:in `initialize'
/home/oscar/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/bundler/gems/activeadmin-988b34e77d1f/app/views/active_admin/resource/index.html.arb:1:in `new'
/home/oscar/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/bundler/gems/activeadmin-988b34e77d1f/app/views/active_admin/resource/index.html.arb:1:in `__home_oscar__rbenv_versions_______lib_ruby_gems_______bundler_gems_activeadmin____b__e__d_f_app_views_active_admin_resource_index_html_arb___4298410947655854879_70101451315680'
actionview (4.1.8) lib/action_view/template.rb:145:in `block in render'
activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:161:in `instrument'
actionview (4.1.8) lib/action_view/template.rb:339:in `instrument'
actionview (4.1.8) lib/action_view/template.rb:143:in `render'
actionview (4.1.8) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:55:in `block (2 levels) in render_template'
actionview (4.1.8) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:38:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `instrument'
actionview (4.1.8) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:38:in `instrument'
actionview (4.1.8) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:54:in `block in render_template'
actionview (4.1.8) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:62:in `render_with_layout'
actionview (4.1.8) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:53:in `render_template'
actionview (4.1.8) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:17:in `render'
actionview (4.1.8) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:42:in `render_template'
actionview (4.1.8) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:23:in `render'
actionview (4.1.8) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:99:in `_render_template'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_controller/metal/streaming.rb:217:in `_render_template'
actionview (4.1.8) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:82:in `render_to_body'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:32:in `render_to_body'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_controller/metal/renderers.rb:32:in `render_to_body'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:25:in `render'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:16:in `render'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:41:in `block (2 levels) in render'
activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:12:in `block in ms'
/home/oscar/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/benchmark.rb:303:in `realtime'
activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:12:in `ms'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:41:in `block in render'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:84:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
activerecord (4.1.8) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:25:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:40:in `render'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:10:in `default_render'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_controller/metal/responder.rb:238:in `default_render'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_controller/metal/responder.rb:165:in `to_html'
responders (1.1.2) lib/responders/flash_responder.rb:107:in `to_html'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_controller/metal/responder.rb:158:in `respond'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_controller/metal/responder.rb:151:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_controller/metal/mime_responds.rb:400:in `respond_with'
inherited_resources (1.6.0) lib/inherited_resources/actions.rb:7:in `index'
/home/oscar/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/bundler/gems/activeadmin-988b34e77d1f/lib/active_admin/resource_controller/streaming.rb:12:in `index'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:189:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:20:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:113:in `call'
activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:113:in `call'
activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `block in halting'
activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `call'
activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `block in halting'
activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `call'
activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `block in halting'
activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:229:in `call'
activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:229:in `block in halting'
activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:229:in `call'
activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:229:in `block in halting'
activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `call'
activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `block in halting'
activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `call'
activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `block in halting'
activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `call'
activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `block in halting'
activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:86:in `call'
activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:86:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:19:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:31:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `instrument'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:250:in `process_action'
activerecord (4.1.8) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:136:in `process'
actionview (4.1.8) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:30:in `process'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:196:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:13:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:232:in `block in action'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:82:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:82:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:50:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:73:in `block in call'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `each'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:678:in `call'
warden (1.2.6) lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `block in call'
warden (1.2.6) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `catch'
warden (1.2.6) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
rack (1.5.5) lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
rack (1.5.5) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in `call'
rack (1.5.5) lib/rack/head.rb:11:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:254:in `call'
rack (1.5.5) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:225:in `context'
rack (1.5.5) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:560:in `call'
activerecord (4.1.8) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:36:in `call'
activerecord (4.1.8) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:621:in `call'
activerecord (4.1.8) lib/active_record/migration.rb:380:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:82:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:73:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:76:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
railties (4.1.8) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
railties (4.1.8) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
railties (4.1.8) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
rack (1.5.5) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
rack (1.5.5) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:26:in `call'
rack (1.5.5) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:84:in `call'
rack (1.5.5) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:112:in `call'
railties (4.1.8) lib/rails/engine.rb:514:in `call'
railties (4.1.8) lib/rails/application.rb:144:in `call'
rack (1.5.5) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
puma (2.15.3) lib/puma/server.rb:541:in `handle_request'
puma (2.15.3) lib/puma/server.rb:388:in `process_client'
puma (2.15.3) lib/puma/server.rb:270:in `block in run'
puma (2.15.3) lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:106:in `call'
puma (2.15.3) lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:106:in `block in spawn_thread'
```

The error occurs when I'm clicking on the Project link in the headbar of the dashboard of activeadmin. Every other link in the headbar shows the data of the model in al list view. Only this model doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that one of these `arr` contains a nil value. If applicable, use `compact` on it before passing it to the methods:

```
arr.compact.each
```

Comment: It still doesn't work. I'm also using the methods just in my seed file.

Comment: Could you give more details then about the error? Maybe where is the error actually happening and some related code?

Comment: I've edited the question. I can't say much more about the error because i'm absolutely clueless.

Comment: I'd try to `binding.pry` (install pry if not there already) before these lines: `Categorization.create`, `Localization.create` and check the value of these variables `cat, log, gro, ag`.